# What is the meaning of this sher?

Tags: poetry, urdu-language, khamoshi-shayari, jaun-eliya

> hamla hai chaar sū dar-o-dīvār-e-shahr kā
>   sab jañgaloñ ko shahr ke andar sameT lo
>
> حملہ ہے چار سُو در و دیوارِ شہر کا 
>   سب جنگلوں کو شہر کے اندر سمیٹ لو

<sub>[Source](https://rekhta.org/couplets/hamla-hai-chaar-suu-dar-o-diivaar-e-shahr-kaa-jaun-eliya-couplets)</sub>

I get the meaning of each word independently, but unable to compile them in order to get the meaning of the whole sher.

What I understand from this: "Someone is attacked by someone from all sides and that person is advising or ordering others to collect all the forests inside the town".

But I don't think that is what Jaun Eliya meant this from the sher.

Comment: Net: I don't speak or read Urdu, so my ability to help you is limited. However, I added the [khamoshi-shayari] tag to your other question because, as best as I could tell, that was the name of the author of that poem. Let me know if that is incorrect (and, if possible, the correct names for both of your questions), and I'll fix that for you. (You won't be able to create new tags on your own until you have 150 reputation points.)

Comment: Shayari seems to be good sense of humour!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain what a sher means, we should first know about what a sher is. and what is there in the sher to understand.

First let me tell you about in a SHER, what does Misra e Oola(first line) and Misra e Saani(Second line) usually represent.

- Misra e Oola in a Sher is Daa'wa(دعویٰ, Claim). So in the first line the writer claims something.
- Misra e Saani in a sher is Daleel (دلیل, Argument). So in the second line, the writer tries to prove what he had claimed above in the first line.

In this Poetic verse, Assume the first person sitting in a Forest/Jungle, Saying that they are under attack by the *Cities* from four of the sides he has claimed that they are under attack and in the second line he provides a solution for it, to Cover all the forest in the cities, this means you should not let the cities to grow and cover all the wild life.

Answer (score 3):

By reading it, it's quite obvious that the literal meaning is:

> Attack of the doors and walls of the city from the four directions
>   Gather all the forests inside the city

Here, the Shayar Jaun Eliya, conveys that the walls of the cities are expanding. So there has to be the deforestation at nearby places. So the shayar asks us to put the forest(s) in the city, i.e., to plant the trees in the city.

Answer (score 0):

Sher is denoted as circumstances which limit you to do whatever you like or want and dar o deewar are the confinements which will never allow you to act or even think with freedom.

Jungle is your desire or wish to achieve something so if you are even confined due to any circumstance, never let your aims get forgotten and keep struggling until you reach your destination.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. It is a bit difficult to make sense of your answer without reading the other answers. Could you please edit it to add information that allows your answer to stand on its own. See also [How can I write good interpretation or meaning answers?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/841/2191) for more guidance on improving your answer.